# Locked sqlite database when debugging

Tags: python, sqlite, locking

Often happens that I debug a python application connecting to sqlite database and during debugging the connection is not closed.

When I debug it next time, the database is locked, so I can't connect to it so I have to edit source code, close connection before the place where exception `database is locked` occur, comment the source code and continue debugging.

Is it possible to unlock the database faster? For example from command line?

thank you

Comment: Why not track down the root of the problem and ensure that the database connection is closed properly before exit?

Comment: @DemianBrecht How would you do it when you interrupt the application while debugging before the connection could be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is locked to other connections when a transaction is in progress.  You can find documentation about SQLite locking [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html).

However you can still access the database via the connection that has locked it.  You can stick that in a global variable or something similar while debugging.